# Ionic cordova run [platform] –prod –release throws typescript error Cannot write file error

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2

I’ve used jquery module in my app all the way and so far no problem. The problem is triggered when I export application dev to prod version “`ionic cordova run [platform] --prod --release`”. I’ve got the following error.

> typescript error Cannot write file
>   ‘…/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js’ because it would overwrite
>   input file.

I’ve been googling about solutions the whole day and still can’t get the right one. The following is my tsconfig.json. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this one. Thank you!

```
{
  “compilerOptions”: {
    “allowJs”: true,
    “allowSyntheticDefaultImports”: true,
    “declaration”: false,
    “emitDecoratorMetadata”: true,
    “experimentalDecorators”: true,
    “lib”: [
      “dom”,
      “es2015”
    ],
    “module”: “es2015”,
    “moduleResolution”: “node”,
    “sourceMap”: true,
    “target”: “es5”
  },
  “include”: [
    “src//*.ts" ], “exclude”: [ “node_modules”, "src//.spec.ts", "src/**/tests/.ts”
  ],
  “compileOnSave”: false,
  “atom”: {
    “rewriteTsconfig”: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "ionic cordova run android --livereload"  or "ionic cordova build android --prod"

Comment: When i run with "ionic cordova run android --livereload", everything is fine. It only happened when I run with "ionic cordova run [platform] --prod --release" this. Thank you.